# SF Communities: Welcome Email not getting populated

Tags: visualforce, community, email, email-template

I have a scenario where in a 'Welcome Email' needs to be sent a new Community User after the Community User has been created (by converting the Contact to External User).

We are using a visual force email template and not the standard welcome email.
The VF email is working correctly for the System Admin profile, but it is not working for different profiles. Can anyone kindly let me know as to how I can make the Welcome Email work for different profile's too.

PS: I have done the changes in My Communities Settings and updated my VF Email template from the standard Community Welcome Email.

Comment: Have you added other profiles to community ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that you add the profiles to the community. Probably for the moment only system administrator is added.

You can add the profiles by going to
Setup > Communities > All Communities > Manage > Administration > Members

There you can add the profiles
[image]

Now an important aspect here is do not remove the system administrator as you won't have access anymore to the community setup.

Comment: Thanks Sven, I tried the same approach but it is still not reflecting for the other profile. Any ideas as to why it is failing to send welcome emails for the added profile.